# How to create slideshow with views using images from node's field

Tags: 7, entities, media, views

I have a field in **Page** content type. Field's type is **Image**. It can contain **unlimited** number of images. I want to use this field for **Slideshow** (module `views_slideshow`). I need to create view for showing content of this field sorted by field's delta and showed like Slideshow. I have a problem with sorting, and showing field items as images (I also need to apply images style to my images).

Is it possible?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/views-slideshow-from-single-node http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49590/views-slideshow-with-multi-value-imagefield

Comment: @Nikit, Thanks! The first link is exactly what I need. I didn't find it using search.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck with [galleryformatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) it's easy to use and works.

The module allows you to select a gallery formatter for an image field.